# Изменение цвета drawable объекта

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли изменить цвет `.png` объекта программно?
Есть иконка `navigationDrawer`'a: черные полосы на прозрачном фоне.
Можно ли изменить цвет полос на нужный?

У меня получилось только изменить фон:

```
Drawable mDrawable = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_drawer);
if (mDrawable != null) {
    mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), 
            PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загружаете `Drawable` в `Bitmap`, проходитесь по массиву пикселей, и по вашим определенным условиям меняете цвет нужных пикселей на нужный вам.

Comment: Т.е. проще использовать уже готовые картинки, чтобы сберечь память

Comment: @Regent, есть возможность *править*

Comment: Было бы у меня 1000 репутации - так бы и поступил. А так - правка в 1 символ, требующая утверждения (не помню, кстати, можно ли предлагать правки в 1 символ), - это не серьёзно.